# Angular2 local template variable VS component property under same name

Tags: angular

All:

I am pretty new to Angular2, when I tried user input, I used a template local variable like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input #userinput (input)="0" />
    <div>{{userinput.value}}</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  userinput = {value:"inside component"};
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to **use the userinput property inside the component rather than the local template variable from input element**? Or I have to use diff names

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference local template's variable with `@ViewChild()` decorator:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('userinput') userinput;
}
```

Note that you'll have to wait a bit before you can access `userinput` value, it's available in `AfterViewInit()` hook: http://plnkr.co/edit/cSY6n76Wonf3TskOhth1.

Comment: Thanks, so this means both component property and local template variable refer to same thing( the Input DOM) now?

Comment: @Kuan Yes, `input`is just wrapped as [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ElementRef-class.html). You can get the actual DOM element with userinput.nativeElement.

Comment: Thanks, got it. But if I do need two seperated variable(one is for local template variable, the other is for component property), is there a way to do what I want( which is using value from componnet property)

Comment: Just use different variable name in your component `@ViewChild('userinput') somethingelse;`

Comment: Ok. I will do that. Ask this just for curious reason.